# Regex to validate entire multiline text in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation

I need some help. 

I have to construct a regex for angularjs ng-pattern attribute.
The regex has to validate a text, not each line or some pieces. The text has to contains some amounts with exactly 2 decimals and each amount should be entered in the new line. Also, spaces are accepted before and after each amount.
If one line contains 2 amount then the entire text is not valid.

For example this text is valid because each amount is entered in the new line:

```
123.34 
12345.56
2.54
```

This example is not valid because one line contains 2 amounts:

```
12.43
123.32 2345.54
124.43
```

This example is not valid because one amount does not contains 2 decimal(each amounts has to be with exactly 2 decimals):

```
123
123.43
123.65
```

My best try is `^(([0-9]+[.][0-9]{2})\s*)+$` and it can be tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/zHtK6h/1). But my regex it's not enough because it accept text with multiple amounts in the same line.

Thanks

Comment: Can there be leading / trailing spaces on the lines? Try `^\d+\.\d{2}(?:\r?\n\d+\.\d{2})*$` if not, see https://regex101.com/r/E5l3SB/1 demo.

Comment: Yes, leading / trailing spaces are accepted.

Comment: Then try [`/^[^\S\r\n]*\d+\.\d{2}(?:[^\S\r\n]*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*\d+\.\d{2})*[^\S\r\n]*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/E5l3SB/2).

Comment: Thank you WiktorStribiżew, it is perfect.

Comment: I posted the answer explaining the regex and explained it together with how you may tweak it and how it interacts with `ng-trim`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
ng-pattern="/^[^\S\r\n]*\d+\.\d{2}(?:[^\S\r\n]*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*\d+\.\d{2})*[^\S\r\n]*$/"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E5l3SB/2).

Or, since angular trims the input before sending it to the regex engine by default (if you have no `ng-trim` or if you have `ng-trim="true"`), you may also use

```
ng-pattern="/^\d+\.\d{2}(?:[^\S\r\n]*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*\d+\.\d{2})*$/"
```

Or, if you want to make sure there are no empty lines at start/end, use the first regex with `ng-trim="false"`.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - any 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `\d{2}` - 2 digits
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching...

  - `[^\S\r\n]*` - any 0+ horizontal whitespaces
  - `\r?\n` - a line break sequence
  - `[^\S\r\n]*\d+\.\d{2}`  - any 0+ horizontal whitespaces, 1+ digits, `.` and 2 digits
- `)*` - ... zero or more times
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - any 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 6):

Regex is not my strong point, so there may be a much simpler way to do this, but this does meet your requirements:

```
^(([^\S\r\n]*[0-9]+[.][0-9]{2}[^\S\r\n]*)\n)*(([^\S\r\n]*[0-9]+[.][0-9]{2}[^\S\r\n]*))$
```

Effectively what it does is ensure that the last line (without a newline character at the end) is always present, but also allows for optional lines before that which end with a newline (\n).

We also use the `[^\S\r\n]` part in place of `\s` to ensure that it checks for whitespace characters excluding newline, as the newline is what causes an issue with validating multiple values on the same line.

[Here is a working example](https://regex101.com/r/uW4WxU/3)

Comment: This does not validate the input if one line contains tab (\t). Except that, it is a good regex for my needs. Thanks

Comment: @GryphG: You didn't mention that in your question though... so, is it spaces and tabs? Or something else you haven't mentioned either? I have updated the answer to support tabs

Comment: That was my mistake. Now i mentioned everything.

Comment: The `[ \t]` still does not match lots of other horzontal whitespace (like hard space). Besides, quantifying the left part makes the regex perform slightly worse compared to the variation where the right part closer to `$` is quantified.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: OP only asked for spaces, and then subsequently tabs. OP has now commented those are the only 2 requirements

Comment: @musefan I see, I just noted that because `[ \t]` only matches ASCII horizontal spaces, `\s` used in the original question, matches all Unicode whitespace in JS regexes. It just seems natural to subtract `\r` and `\n` from the `\s`, hence my suggestion.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Ok I see your point. I did initially try `[^\S\r\n]` but it didn't work, however it's likely it didn't work because I had other bits that didn't work at that exact point anyway

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that `\s` matches also spaces use `[\r\n]` instead to match newlines and cariage return.

EDIT my first post mentioned `\R` but it's PCRE specific.

EDIT following comments to accept also space at the end of line

```
^(([0-9]+[.][0-9]{2}) *(?:\r?\n|$))+$
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zHtK6h/3)

Comment: This doesn't seem to validate the whole text. For example, put a new line at the end that is invalid number, like `12.3`... the whole thing should be a non-match. Also, OP want to accept spaces at the start of the lines too

Comment: fixed, the last `$` was wrongly dropped after moved inside alternation

Answer (score 1):

add the multiline flag `/m` to be able to anchor `^` to the start of each line

`/^([0-9]+[.][0-9]{2})\s*$/gm`

e.g. https://regex101.com/r/XMTSok/4

Comment: if also want leading spaces, you can use `\s*` on front as well, since having modifier/flag `/m` would make it multiline anyway

Comment: This does not validate the input as a single block of text as per the requirements